# Convert string to Title Case, but double quotes in string interfere with mb_convert_case()

Tags: php, regex, string, title-case

I need to convert a string to camel case, it's easy by using:

```
mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8")
```

But what if string contains non-alphanumeric characters:

```
$str = 'he said "hello world"';
echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Result is:

```
He Said "hello World"
```

But I need:

```
He Said "Hello World"
```

Comment: You will probably need to write your own function as they were trying in comments on php.net

Answer (score 2):

With a regular expression.

If you are only going to work with non-accented latin characters, it can be as simple as

```
$str = 'he said "hello WORLD"';
echo preg_replace('/\b([a-z])/e', 'strtoupper(\'$1\')', strtolower($str));
```

This matches any lowercase unaccented latin letter that is preceded by a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). The letter is replaced with its uppercase equivalent.

If you want this to work with other languages and scripts as well, you will have to get fancy:

```
$str = 'he said "καλημέρα ΚΌΣΜΕ"'; // this has to be in UTF-8
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\p{L})(\p{Ll})/eu',
                  'mb_convert_case(\'$1\', MB_CASE_UPPER, \'UTF-8\')',
                  mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8'));
```

To grok this you need to refer to the [Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) functionality of PCRE, and note that I have added the `u` modifier to [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). This matches any unicode letter that has an uppercase equivalent (with the pattern `\p{Ll}`), provided that it is not preceded by any other letter ([negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with the pattern `\p{L}`). It then replaces it with the uppercase equivalent.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/aGPmR)**.

**Update:** It looks like you intend to consider only whitespace as word boundaries. This can be done with the regular expressions

```
(?<=\s|^)([a-z])
(?<=\s|^)(\p{Ll})
```

Comment: What if **$str = "Ryan's shirts are very large";**

Comment: @WebolizeR: You are never going to get this perfect if you think by examples. I can see what the problem is with Ryan's shirts, but you need to specify with meticulous detail how you need the capitalization to work in relation to punctuation before any solution should be attempted. Otherwise each "fix" will present new opportunities for breaking the algorithm with an engineered example.

Comment: ok, @Jon, the only thing I need is that, all words will begin an uppercase character.In my example, **Ryan's** is a single word, but it's converted to **Ryan'S**. By word I mean, every phrase divided by one or more spaces.
tHanks

Comment: @WebolizeR: I 'm not sure if this will work for you that well, but have a look at the update.

Comment: The /e modifier is deprecated since PHP5.5 and no longer supported from PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (according to PHP.net comments)

```
$str = 'he said "hello world"';
echo preg_replace('/([^a-z\']|^)([a-z])/ie', '"$1".strtoupper("$2")', strtolower($str));
```

Comment: The /e modifier is deprecated since PHP5.5 and no longer supported from PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample data only indicates that double quotes are the only source of trouble, extract segments from your string which do not contain double quotes and call the title casing function on each segment.  If you have other characters causing trouble, you'll need to extend your sample data for contributors to better understand the variability of the text.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8BRIp))

```
$strings = [
    'he said "hello worLd"',
    'he sAId "καλημέρα ΚΌΣΜΕ" to me',
    "Ryan's shirts are verY large",
];
var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/[^"]+/',
        fn($m) => mb_convert_case($m[0], MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8"),
        $strings
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'He Said "Hello World"',
  1 => 'He Said "Καλημέρα Κόσμε" To Me',
  2 => 'Ryan\'s Shirts Are Very Large',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

use manual! :D found on php.net

```
<?php

function ucwordsEx($str, $separator){

      $str = str_replace($separator, " ", $str);
      $str = ucwords(strtolower($str));
      $str = str_replace(" ", $separator, $str);
      return $str;

}
/*
Example:
*/
echo ucwordsEx("HELLO-my-NAME-iS-maNolO", "-");
/*
Prints: "Hello My Name Is Manolo"
*/

?>
```

Comment: This unexplained answer does not work with the asker's sample input string. https://3v4l.org/enau5

Answer (score -1):

here is very simple code

```
echo  ucwords('he said '.ucwords('"hello world"')) ;
```

**output** He Said Hello World

Comment: I think it is very sensible to say that the desired solution will need to work on the whole string and that most developers aren't able to hardcode a nested call like this.